# Can a click handler be an object?

Tags: javascript, events, click, google-plus-one

I'm trying to register on +1 clicks from within my module, which is wrapped as an annonymous function.

For this end, I created a global object MyModule, and exported my click handler function through it. The problem is - my click handler doesn't get called.

[Live demo](http://jsbin.com/ivodim/2). Code:

```
// Initialize +1 button
gapi.plusone.go();


(function(){
  window.MyModule = {};

  function plusOneClicked() {
    alert("+1!");
  }

  window.MyModule.plusOneClicked = plusOneClicked;
})()

...

<g:plusone callback='window.MyModule.plusOneClicked'></g:plusone>
```

When I give as a callback an external function, whose only purpose is to forward the calls to window.MyModule.plusOneClicked, it works:

```
function foo() {
  window.MyModule.plusOneClicked();
}
...
<g:plusone callback='foo'></g:plusone>
```

Why would the click handler miss window.MyModule.plusOneClicked(), but find foo()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is probably writing

```
window[callback]();
```

in their code.

This requires that the `callback` string refer to a property of `window`, not a property of another object.

Answer (score 0):

I believe because `callback` expects a direct handler **method** (as in `foo()`) rather than a **reference** (as in `window.MyModule.plusOneClicked`). So basically, you cannot simply assign  such a reference to click handler, but write a (wrapper) method as the handler and have it perform the necessary invocation.